# Mocha doesn't exit when using Istanbul for code coverage

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, istanbul

I'm using Mocha 5 which requires `mocha --exit` to run tests. Then I try to add istanbul for code coverage by running `istanbul cover node_modules/mocha/bin/_mocha`. In this case mocha  cannot exit. Is there any way to add an exit flag like `--exit`?

I have tried Mocha 3 which works fine.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use [nyc](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nyc) for this purpose. And test can be run like this

```
nyc --cache mocha modules/**/*.spec.js routes/*.spec.js --exit
```

or this

```
node_modules/.bin/nyc --cache node_modules/.bin/mocha modules/**/*.spec.js routes/*.spec.js --exit
```

Answer (score 0):

This came up at the top of my search for the issue, but I didn't want to use nyc.

What worked instead was to put `--exit` into `.mocha.opts`.